# No service in the UK, what baseband modem firmware should I try and flash?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, baseband

I have a Galaxy S3 running CyanogenMod 13 and I had always assumed it was locked or something because I could never get any service in the UK. When I went abroad I noticed I could get roaming service.

I came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWdgWzFdla0) which seems to describe my problem and a solution to it. I notice though that the baseband firmware download they suggest (`I9300XXUGMK6`) is an Irish one [according to Sammobile.com](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-I9300/VDI/). `I9300XXUGMK6` is actually the baseband version my phone reports now. Is the problem maybe that I am running and Irish baseband version in the UK or does it not work like that?

EDIT: So I found out that `I9300XXUGMK6` is called `PDA` and describes the device I have and there are a few different versions available for that device. The most logical baseband firmware for me then would be the I9300XXUGMK6_I9300O2UGNA1_O2U.zip since I am on GiffGaff which uses the O2 network. But I can't actually find this for download anywhere though.

Comment: https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s-/GT-I9300/O2U/download/I9300XXUGMK6/24609/ It says the file has been archived due to few downloads, and there's a link to a contact form to request the file. Or you could try https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-s-/GT-I9300/O2U/download/I9300XXUGNA5/25827/, which is newer.

Comment: Thanks yeah, I will try the request but am not too hopeful. Any ideas what the difference in the PDA (UGMK6 to UGNA5) signifies? Is my device compatible with the newer version?

Comment: I honestly don't know the difference between the two, but I've never had any troubles installing and running a newer version of the firmware as long as it's for the same hardware (GT-I9300 in your case).